# QT Unable to use an autosize QLineEdit & Layout

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a custom widget extending QLineEdit. I want this is 'autosize'. Ok I get it using

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(resizeLineEditToContents()));
```

I have 2 of this widgets. The idea is that a resize of widget 1 is used by the horizontal layout where I have placed the two widgets to place rightly the widget 2.

But it is impossible, I have played with all the policy possible value, without success.

The layout tries always to adjust the size of my `QLineEdit` widget .... (It happens also with a standard `QLineEdit`).
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not necessary to have the signature of signals and slots to be the same, and Qt actually asks in the documentation to not put 'const' and '&' on it because of the 'normalization'. a Signal can have zero to N parameters, a slot can bave zero to Signal-Number-Of-Parameters, so that's why the connect works.

but back to your problem, you need to use setFixedWidth, so it will know to not resize back to the old width just as soon as you stretch it, then set Layout to prefered, so it will respect your widget's hints.